# Tensorflow - Read and Save TFRecords to Dict and Use Multiprocessing

Tags: tensorflow, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to speed up the conversion of select tfrecords to a series of python dictionaries. Here's what I have. Initially the CPU utilization spikes, but then goes to almost zero, suggesting my code is not working correctly.

My goal is to have 3 dictionaries saved and pickled. There are 14,000+ tfrecord files (2 gigs appx). At the current rate, it will take about 84 hours to run on a single process.

Are there any problems with my use of manage dicts

```py
import glob
import tensorflow as tf
import cPickle
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

import collections
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Pool



def get_multihot_encoding(example_label):
    enc = np.zeros(10)
    for label in example_label:
        if label in lookup.values():
            index = lookup_inverted[label]
            enc[index] = 1
    return list(enc)


# Set-up MultiProcessing
manager = Manager()
audio_embeddings_dict = manager.dict()
audio_labels_dict = manager.dict()
audio_multihot_dict = manager.dict()
sess = tf.Session()

# The iterable which gets passed to the function
all_tfrecord_filenames = glob.glob('/Users/jeff/features/audioset_v1_embeddings/unbal_train/*.tfrecord')



def process_tfrecord(tfrecord):

  for idx, example in enumerate(tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(tfrecord)): 
    tf_example = tf.train.Example.FromString(example)
    vid_id = tf_example.features.feature['video_id'].bytes_list.value[0].decode(encoding='UTF-8')
    example_label = list(np.asarray(tf_example.features.feature['labels'].int64_list.value))

    # Non zero intersect of 2 sets is True - only create dict entries if this is true!
    if set(example_label) & label_filters:
        print(set(example_label) & label_filters, " Is the intersection of the two")
        tf_seq_example = tf.train.SequenceExample.FromString(example)
        n_frames = len(tf_seq_example.feature_lists.feature_list['audio_embedding'].feature)
        audio_frame = []    

        for i in range(n_frames):
            audio_frame.append(tf.cast(tf.decode_raw(
                 tf_seq_example.feature_lists.feature_list['audio_embedding'].feature[i].bytes_list.value[0],tf.uint8)
                ,tf.float32).eval(session=sess))

        audio_embeddings_dict[vid_id] = audio_frame
        audio_labels_dict[vid_id] = example_label
        audio_multihot_dict[vid_id] = get_multihot_encoding(example_label)
        #print(get_multihot_encoding(example_label), "Is the encoded label")

    if idx % 100 == 0:  
        print ("Saving dictionary at loop: {}".format(idx))
        cPickle.dump(audio_embeddings_dict, open('audio_embeddings_dict_unbal_train_multi_{}.pkl'.format(idx), 'wb'))
        cPickle.dump(audio_multihot_dict, open('audio_multihot_dict_bal_untrain_multi_{}.pkl'.format(idx), 'wb'))
        cPickle.dump(audio_multihot_dict, open('audio_labels_unbal_dict_multi_{}.pkl'.format(idx), 'wb'))




pool = Pool(50)
result = pool.map(process_tfrecord, all_tfrecord_filenames)
```

Comment: Multiple problems. You are spawning 50 threads and that is probably the cause of the CPU spike you are seeing. Just because you are running a ot of threads doesn't mean things get processed faster, it just means you invite more opportunities for deadlocks and race conditions. To speed things up you should probably run one thread per core of your CPU. But if I am reading it correctly, most of your code seems to be I/O rather than CPU bound, so making it multithreaded is likely to make things worse. Try to go back to single thread and use profiler to find out where all the time is spent.

Comment: Not IO bound, just reformatting data locally

Comment: Yes, but most of what your code is doing seems to be reading and writing files. That is I/O.